# Multiple call function not working properly

Tags: vb.net, call, procedure

This is my general sub to remove a players card and add it to the discard pile. Then a number is generated and represents a card in my quantity integerarray.

The grab variables in here represent values from a grab card being played, then the defender can defender against the grab and then grab the offender if they have both a block and a grab. The grab 1 through 3 variables in my code represent the different steps in the process.  Grab 1 logic sets it to remove the defenders block card. Grab 2 removes the defenders grab card, grab 3 removes offenders grab card.

Grab 1 or removal of the block card works as it is suppose to, as well as grab 3. However for some reason Grab 2 doesn't work properly. Instead it replaces The card slot where the block was twice. Grab 1 removes the block, and for some reason grab 2 is removing the replacement.

```
Private Sub GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
        'ReDeclare CheckBox Array for Private sub
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}


        CardCheckBoxArray(NumberArrayStorageForSpecialCards Mod 5).Checked = False
        If Grab = 1 Then
            'set checks to the number in the number array set for block
            Checks = DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.CheckGrabs
        ElseIf Grab = 2 Then
            'set checks to the number in the number array set for grab
            GrabGone = (T * 5)
            Do Until GrabGone = (T * 5) + 4 Or Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(GrabGone)).ID = 19
                MsgBox(GrabGone)
                If Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(GrabGone)).CardNameString = "Grab" Then
                    Checks = GrabGone
                End If
                GrabGone += 1
            Loop
        ElseIf Grab = 3 Then
            'set checks to number that will remove offending players grab
            PlayerTemp2 = T
            T = DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp
            Checks = NumberArrayStorageForSpecialCards
        End If
        'Discard
        Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger(T) -= 1
        'Add Card to Discard Pile
        DiscardGroup(NumberArray(Checks)).QuantityInteger(0) += 1
        'Shuffle Deck from Discard Pile if Deck is out of cards
        Call DiscardPile()
        'Reset Number Generator, unless weapon isn't discard
        Call RandomNumberGenerator()

        If DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0) > 0 Then
            DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(0) -= 1
            'Select the Player depending value of T
            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger(T) += 1

            NumberArray(Checks) = Number

            If Grab <> 3 Then
                For FillCheckBoxes As Integer = 5 * T To (5 * T) + 4
                    CardCheckBoxArray(FillCheckBoxes Mod 5).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(FillCheckBoxes)).CardNameString
                Next
            End If
        End If


        'Remove Defending players block card
        If Grab = 1 Then
            Grab = 2
            Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
            Exit Sub
            'Remove defending players Grab card
        ElseIf Grab = 2 Then
            Grab = 3
            Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
            Exit Sub
            'Remove offenders Grab card
        ElseIf Grab = 3 Then
                Grab = 0
                GrabInPlace = False
                T = PlayerTemp2
                Exit Sub
        End If

        Call SpecialCards()

    End Sub
```